# Map element in column to its position in another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this little issue that I cannot resolve. I've tried several things without any success. So, to put this into context:

I have a number of objects with known positions. In my set up, I even have devices calculating their position (trilateration, but it's not important to this question).

```
Place True position Calculated position
0    X1       [A,B,C]           [A,C,D,F]
1    X2       [D,E,F]               [E,H]
2    X3         [G,H]               [G,A]
```

So, in `Place`, `X1` objects `A,C` were detected where they truly are, but `D,F` were detected there though they are in `X2`.  So, to know which elements are not supposed to be found in `X1` I do the following

```
df['Position difference'] = df['Calculated position'].map(set) - df['True position'].map(set) 
def convert(set):
    return list(set)
df['Position difference'] = df['Position difference'].apply(convert)
```

which returns:

```
Place True position Calculated position Position difference
0    X1       [A,B,C]           [A,C,D,F]              [F, D]
1    X2       [D,E,F]               [E,H]                 [H]
2    X3         [G,H]               [G,A]                 [A]
```

What I want to do is create a column in which the elements would be the place where the elements in `Position difference` actually are:

```
Place True position Calculated position   Diff    Pos
0    X1       [A,B,C]           [A,C,D,F]  [D,F]  X2,X2
1    X2       [D,E,F]               [E,H]    [H]     X3
2    X3         [G,H]               [G,A]    [A]     X1
```

I tried using df.iloc but it got so messy I didn't know what to do. The end-game is to be able to say how far an element is found from its actual position. For instance, if `X1,X2,X3` are adjacent to one another, then `D,F` are found 1 section away from where they actually are.

Truly grateful for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code to get you started:

```
def func():
    l, d = [], {}
    for p, t, c in df.to_numpy():
        l.append([*set(c) - set(t)])
        d.update(dict.fromkeys(t, p))
    
    for item in l:
        yield item, ','.join(map(d.get, item))

df[['diff', 'Pos']] = [*func()]
```

---

```
print(df)

  Place True position Calculated position    diff    Pos
0    X1     [A, B, C]        [A, C, D, F]  [F, D]  X2,X2
1    X2     [D, E, F]              [E, H]     [H]     X3
2    X3        [G, H]              [G, A]     [A]     X1
```

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes Happy coding!

Comment: This fails if ```set(c)``` is empty (That is True position is []).  I tried to fix this by ```if(len(set(c)!=0): ``` and so on, but I don't get it right. Any ideas?

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes Which error are you getting?

Comment: ```TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found``` with ```---> 11         yield item, ','.join(map(d.get, item)) ```. I checked: This only happens with empty lists in the True position column (I guess because ``` l.append([*set(c) - set(t)])
``` can't be computed.

Comment: I think this happens when there is a key in `calculated position` column which does not match any keys from `True postion` column. How do you want to handle such case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237063/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-serge-de-gosson-de-varennes).